# reduced adjective clause or adverbial?

Tags: grammar, meaning, adjectives, relative-clauses, adverbial-phrases

*These* are machines that take room air and extract the nitrogen, **producing** greater than %90 pure oxygen.

Is '' producing ''reduced adjective clause or adverbial?

Comment: [Adjective clauses](http://www.skesl.com/grammar/book/adjective-adverb-noun-clauses) are placed after the noun it is modifying. Adjective clauses start with a pronoun. An adverb clause provides a description and functions as an adverb. It contains a subject and a verb but it does not express a complete thought and cannot stand alone as a complete sentence.

Comment: Side note: The percent sign goes after the number. "90%", not "%90".

Comment: I'd say it's a participial clause functioning as an adjunct (your adverbial), i.e. a modifier in clause structure.